# Почему mongoose в history не пишет, а в hist пишет?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

как известно `mongo` модифицирует название таблиц, если задать название `table` оно будет преобразовано в множественное число - `tables`

у меня появилась сущность `history` и удивительное дело `mongo` преобразовал ее по правилам в `histories`

но почему-то отказался в нее записывать данные:

```
var data = {
    id: 1,
    name: "user1",
    value: 10
}
var modelHistory = mongoose.model('Hystory', myShema),
    table = new modelHistory(data)
table.save(function(err) {
    err && console.log(err);
});
```

после переименования модели все заработало:

```
var modelHistory = mongoose.model('Hyst', myShema),
```

правильно ли я понимаю, что `монго` некорректно работает `исключениями` в английском языке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, Вы понимаете неправильно. MongoDB сама по себе не меняет название коллекции - проблема в использовании JS модуля Mongoose. Кроме бага с переименованием коллекций (или фичи, с какой стороны смотреть), в этом модуле есть также еще несколько не совсем очевидных особенностей. Подробнее это было описано в [этой статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/253395/) на хабре